# How to avoid ModelAdmin options being overridden in subclasses?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-modeladmin

I have a generic ModelAdmin in my `admin.py` which replaces some widgets in the admin interface. It serves as a superclass for all my other ModelAdmins. It looks like this:

```
#in mainapp/admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from suit.widgets import SuitSplitDateTimeWidget

class SuitedUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField: {
            'widget': SuitSplitDateTimeWidget
        },
        #(...)
    }
    #(...)
```

In a different Django app, I use `SuitedUpAdmin` as a superclass for a ModelAdmin that also tries to replace some of the widgets:

```
#in events/admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from suit.widgets import AutosizedTextarea
from mainapp.admin import SuitedUpAdmin

class LocationAdmin(SuitedUpAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': AutosizedTextarea},
    }
    #(...)
```

The problem is, when I assign a new value to `formfield_overrides` in `LocationAdmin`, I lose the previous value inherited from `SuitedUpAdmin`. How can I deal with this? The solution I'm currently using is replacing widget instances in a `LocationAdmin.render_change_form` method, but I'm looking for more elegant and readable options. I'd like to avoid using ModelForms for this. Looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `formfield_overrides` from the base class `SuitedUpAdmin` with a dict:

```
class LocationAdmin(SuitedUpAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = dict(SuitedUpAdmin.formfield_overrides, **{
        models.TextField: {'widget': AutosizedTextarea},
    })
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could execute `.update(...)` in there, thanks!
It's sad that I can't use `super`, but maybe close enough.

Comment: Oh, but there's a bug in the code you provided: it actually updates its superclass's property, and assigns `None` to its own. I'd solve it by first using `copy()`, and then updating a duplicate dictionary, but maybe you have another idea? Please correct your example!

Comment: @Hellelujah thank you for drawing attention. I've fixed the example.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your answer - it pointed me in the right direction. What I actually used is: `formfield_overrides = SuitedUpAdmin.formfield_overrides.copy()`, and then `formfield_overrides.update(...)` - two lines instead of a single statement, but I think it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an @property to access the attribute of super (I have not tried this under Django admin, but pure Python example works fine):

```
class SuperAttributes(object):
    formfield_overrides = {
        'field.Something': 'overrides'
    }


class ChildAttributes(SuperAttributes):
    @property
    def formfield_overrides(self):
        attrs = super(ChildAttributes, self).formfield_overrides
        attrs['field.SomethingElse'] = 'overrides'
        return attrs


child = ChildAttributes()
print child.formfield_overrides
```

**EDIT**: More Pythonic inherited class

```
class ChildAttributes(SuperAttributes):
    @property
    def formfield_overrides(self):
        attrs = super(ChildAttributes, self).formfield_overrides
        attrs.update({
            'field.SomethingElse': 'overrides'
        })
        return attrs
```

Comment: That's very interesting. I'd rather avoid an overhead of calling a method every time I need the value of the property, byt thanks for teaching me about that `@property` decorator.

Comment: @Hellelujah the issue is that you can not assign the return of `.update()` since `.update()` does not return dictionary itself.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that - at the moment, in my `LocationAdmin`, I did `formfield_overrides = SuitedUpAdmin.formfield_overrides.copy()` and then `formfield_overrides.update(...)`. It isn't as flexible as I'd like it to be (why doesn't `super` work here?!), but it is a fair compromise for me between elegance and performance. But that's my opinion - what do you think?

Comment: But how did you do `.copy()` and `.update()` in a class attribute assignment statement? I am confused :| @Hellelujah

Comment: I did exactly what i've written in the previous comment. Try it yourself: http://repl.it/TbX